# Rails name error after Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, react-rails

I have two JSON file in my rails project

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array! @restaurants, partial: 'restaurants/restaurant', as: :restaurant
```

and **_restaurant.json.jbuilder**

```
json.(restraurant, :id, :name, :address, :description)
```

When i render my component on my index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component('RestaurantList', {name: raw(render(template: 'restaurants/index.json.jbuilder')) }) %>
```

I get this error.

**NameError in Restaurants#index**

```
undefined local variable or method `restraurant' for #<#<Class:0x007ffd1f6a61b0>:0x007ffd22e2bea0>
Did you mean?  restaurant
               restaurant_url
               restaurant_path
               restaurants_url
               restaurants_path
               @restaurants

Extracted source (around line #1):
1

json.(restraurant, :id, :name, :address, :description)
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In your render call, you're doing this:

```
render(template: 'restaurants/index.json.jbuilder')
```

and you should be doing this:

```
render(template: 'restaurants/index', formats: :json)
```

This tells Rails that you're trying to render a JSON formatted output.  Using the filename to communicate intent won't work.  Use the `format:` option, instead.

And in your **_restaurant.json.jbuilder** file, change the code to this:

```
json.(restaurant, :id, :name, :address, :description)
```

That should take care of that `undefined local variable or method` error.

Comment: Can u look my last answer? i change there something

Comment: I'm happy to look at the information and see what I can find.  It needs to be in a new question.  Please accept my answer that solved the `undefined local variable or method error` question that you originally asked.  You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer, and it will change color to green.

Answer (score 0):

yes i did and somethings happened but i can't anyway get data with json. I already change all with new controller so what i did :

Here is my post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
```

and here is my views/posts/index.html.erb file

```
<%= react_component('PostList', {name: raw(render(template: 'posts/index', formats: :json)) }) %>
```

here is views/posts/index.json.jbuilder file

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :title, :body
  json.url post_url(post, format: :json)
end
```

here is views/posts/show.json.jbuilder file

```
json.extract! @post, :id, :title, :body, :created_at, :updated_at
```

here is my react component file assets/javascripts/components/post_list.js.jsx

```
var PostList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {  
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.parse(this.props.posts).map(function(post) { 
          return <Post key={post.id} {... post}  />;
        })}
      </div>
      );
  }
```

});

I can add post with rails-admin all is working i just want to render this posts with json to view files. But this is showing to me nothing

Comment: You should not add more information to your question by posting an answer.  You can use the `edit` button located beneath the question to add more information.  Please move this information to the question and delete this answer.

Comment: Actually, this is a new question.  You should create a new question with this information.  It's important on StackOverflow to ask one question and let that be answered.  New problems need to have new questions.